# Saving, storing, and changing data with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, save, store

I'm trying to make a script that saves the page of a pdf by:

1. saving the name
2. saving the page number

then I want to be able to type into the python console something like "Book 1"

then it would ask "page #?"

Then I type "32"

then it saves "Book 1 page 32"

Then the next time I type "Book 1"

I want it to return "Page 32"

And if I want to update the page I type something like Book 1 update, and it saves the new page number I enter.

How do I go about saving info like this? I know I could change the code each time but at that point its basically a .txt file.

Is there a common way of creating save files like this that can be modified later in python?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear here. Are you referring to saving a page of a pdf (as another pdf)? Do you want a new pdf with all the pages of the given file? Is "Book 1" a pdf file name?

Comment: No I'm not sure how it works. I don't want the page number saved as a pdf. But im not sure what file type or whatnot is used to save information with python.

Comment: Basically how companies save username data and store and search it. I want something like that.

Comment: They typically use things like a [relational database](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/question599.htm). Though that doesn't have to do with Python directly (it can but not likely what you are looking for) If you want to save Python structures and objects, consider researching [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle)